# Sql query with count, inner join, groupby to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

i am writing a LINQ query but i have no idea of LINQ but i know how to write sql Query , someone please help and give me exact answer. thanks in advance

```
      select count(t.taskid),
             t.userid 
        from task t, 
             userr u 
       where u.userid = t.userid 
    group by t.userid;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: `I am writing a LINQ query, but i have no idea of LINQ`; how are you writing one if you have no idea of linq? If this is the case you are asking `can someone write a linq query for me`, we help with specific issues and or problems and currently you haven't shown an attempt at this.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but to make the aliases in LINQ, you have to switch just a few things around from the SQL way.

- The select always goes at the end.
- Aliases look like assignment statements.
- I didn't test this, also you should use the LINQ join method. This is just to illustrate SQL-LINQ one-for-one.

  ```
  var items=
      from t=task,
           u=user
     where u.userid = t.userid 
  group by t.userid;
  select count(t.taskid), t.userid   <=== you can't do this, BTW, get rid of t.userid
  ```